# Server improperly handling unicode characters?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, buffer-overflow, encoding

So I'm pen-testing a web application. Upon submitting certain data it sends it in a `POST` request which contains the data in a JSON object. So while fuzzing it I was testing for improper encoding handling. Sure enough when sending a unicode character in the format `\u2030` I get a response from the server complaining about the bogus data.

However, when it tells me what I sent to it instead of having the character per mille `‰` which is what `\u2030` is I get this JSON object containing three separate characters for the unicode character I entered:

```
{"success": false, "errorcode": 1, 
"errormessage": "Section 'init' or action 'Èƒ0' is invalid"}
```

The `Èƒ0' is invalid` part being the part of interest. I'm curious as to whether or not this may reveal a potential security risk in the form of a buffer overflow because one of the 3 bytes comprising the unicode character could be interpreted as a null byte then having more data after it that will overwrite other memory.

Any info, advice, etc would be great. Thanks.

EDIT: It just occurred to me that Burp, which I'm using to intercept the response, may be incorrectly displaying the unicode character when the server responds with it. Is this a known bug?

Comment: If you suspect  a bug in BURP, I recommend reaching out to Portswigger.

Comment: Do you know what language the server application is written in?

Comment: @Anders Based on the error messages I've gotten back from other tests I would say JavaScript